# "Low Quality Posts" queue full with no posts

Tags: bug

For many months now, for me at least, the Review Queue list has been showing the "Low Quality Posts" as very busy (with the red dot), but when I visit the queue, the list is empty.

[image] [image]

Is it full of posts of mine; is this a bug; or what's going on?

**Update**: right now it's back to normal, after ANeves emptied the queue. This probably means it's not a solution, just a temporary respite.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think your guess is as accurate as possible: there **are** items in the queue, but I guess that they're not visible to you.
Perhaps you've already signalled them, or they're not visible to you for some other reason.

Regardless, this is very clearly a UX bug.
Either you *have* items and can't see them -a bug-, or you have a notification but have *no items* -a bug-.

---

Here's one example of an existing item in the queue - note that it's indeed a month old:

[image: a sample of something in the review queue]

Comment: Thanks. I'm not 100% sure, but I think I indeed already voted on the example you give. Can you report this bug?

Comment: @stafusa Ugh, that sounds bothersome... I'm actually going on holiday out of the country for 3 days -how convenient! :D- , so can I bounce that back to you? I think that the proper way is to post it in https://meta.stackexchange.com/ with the tag bug, like you did here; and there it'll be picked up by the devs or CMs or whomever deals with this. Or you can be patient and I'll take a look at reporting this on Friday. :)

Comment: It's fine, I've posted it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344163/369732) now. It appears it might be only an ill-set parameter, let's see what they answer - I wonder if it might be a problem that, right now, the red dot isn't showing any more for me...